# Is there a JenkinsCI plugin for WebSphere Portal 6.1?

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, websphere-portal

Is there a JenkinsCI plugin for WebSphere Portal 6.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do either of these help?

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WAS+Builder+Plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+WebSphere+Plugin

Comment: Thank you, first is what i need. the second is not suitable because of restriction "WebSphere Application Server 6.1 (with security disabled)"

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own ant tasks, jython scripts and just called them from jenkins